# Using WhiteNoise with Django to serve directories of HTML files

Tags: django, whitenoise

I'm using [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io) successfully to serve all my Django site's static files under a `/static/` path.

I'd also like to have a couple of other directories of HTML files, images, etc served at different paths (e.g. `/foo/my_file.html` and `/bar/hello.html`).

I think Whitenoise [lets you add further directories using `add_files()`](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/base.html#using-whitenoise-with-any-wsgi-application) but I can't figure out how to use this with a Django site that's using the `DjangoWhiteNoise` class, and with a `wsgi.py` that currently looks like:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Won't the [WHITENOISE_ROOT](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#WHITENOISE_ROOT) setting do what you want?

Comment: I was going to say "I'm using it already, and only for files you want available at the root level of the site like `robots.txt`" and then stopped and thought, "Oh, but what if I put my extra directories of static files in there…?" And yes, it works! That's brilliant! Thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.